# Old app with no Xib and storyboard. Make ios9 compatible

Tags: ios, storyboard, xib, ios9

Iam new to developer forum and in need of help. So thought why not get help from fellow developers. I have a app (Photo Sharing App) that was bought from a developer and now I want to make it ios9 compatible and want to have a app with more effects and features like ; masking, layers, crop, resize, stickers etc....

Had a developer look at it and he told me this about the app. 
"— App Code is Static. (no xibs and no storyboard used). All code written programatically. >> if to make compatible to iOS9 have to re-structure re-code all the structure to match with latest app requirement storyboard,auto layout etc… (current code is static for each devices need to make dynamic). 
— App not working for new xcode 7. 
— Application working in older version of Xcode 6.4. When tried to run on Xcode 7 it shows error not compiling at all. with changes managed to apply fix and run on new Xcode. But it still hangs on iOS 9 
— facebook invite friend not working >> current code has older implementation of Facebook to show just friend with invite list which is now not allow by Facebook. Have to now check for this invite feature how it is working now and what are the steps needed to implement if working. "

The question: Is it any easy solution to make it work or do we need to make the app from scratch. Any one who can guide me to right direction. Where should I start and what can be done. Is it much work related to getting it IOS9 compatible? Any script/codes available on the net/github? iam just a amateur and on starting level so please consider it.

Have heard that can make a launch screen with storyboard so no need to make the app from scratch and just let the lauchscreen be dynamic to work with the app for flexible layout. How is that possible?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to remake all views with storyboard or xibs. You just need to add Default images for 3.5 and 4 inches iPhones. Also, you need to fix all errors, update frameworks and libs, recode deprecated methods, make the app compile for 64 bit architecture.

Comment: Still its going to be a lot of work to get it there. Not a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. Do you think it will be a mandatory anytime in future having storyboard or Xib? And also tell me by doing as you mentioned above will I be able to use the new features of IOS9 on my app?  Thanks

Comment: @Tander It depends. The point is not to rewrite and redesign everything,

Comment: I concur. Though it is less work to just leave xibs and storyboards out. @kirander No, I doubt it will be required to have them in place and yes you will have access to all iOS9 features without them.

Comment: @SarnaTraders The storyboard or xibs absolutely unnecessary. It is just the method to build the views. Moreover, autolayout is slower, then manual or autoresizing. Yes, you can use all the features from iOS 9. Why not?